# Azure AD B2C magic links authentication

Tags: azure, hyperlink, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am starting my journey with B2C and I am struggling to implement the authentication with magic links.
Can someone send me a link with a more detailed tutorial on the topic?

Thanks

I tried the following tutorial, but the author removed the repository and I cannot implement it.
[text](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r0hjudtpM9E)

Answer (score 0):

There are some samples [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples).

Typically the journey uses an [id-token-hint](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/using-a-jwt-to-invoke-an-azure-ad-b2c-flow-using-id-token-hint-13752ee6d9df).

[This](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/hosting-the-id-token-hint-well-known-endpoint-in-azure-ad-b2c-itself-1c27be147613) may also help.